# QnA maker GA works different with Preview

Tags: bots, azure-qna-maker

I'm a bot developer and I just migrated our QnA from preview to GA. But, then I realised I can't find the answer with what I'm asking previously. Then I did some research from my side, and I found the scores of preview and GA are way to different for a same question. I have attached few screenshots about this issue from both preview and GA.

[1. Screenshot: This is the Question and Answer from QnA preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ulCGo.png)

Then, I'm asking "explain braveheart". In this case, even though I don't have exactly "Explain braveheart" in my question, but QnA should understand what I'm trying to ask. In preview, as we can't see the score from Test portal, so I write a simple program to extract the score from code. Like below:

[2. Screenshot: QnA maker preview works great for this question in my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JvZPQ.png)

Then, I migrated my QnA from preview to GA, and score changed dramatically, like below:

[3. Screenshot: The same question and answers in QnA maker GA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mj80L.png)

Then, this is the result when I test the same question within QnA maker GA.

[4. See the confidence score is way too lower than preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XYRY9.png)

I would like to know why the QnA GA works different with preview, and it is quite important for use to manage our questions and answers. Moreover, if they are performing differently, so we can't simply migrate the QnA KB from preview to GA. This is a huge different with what we have from the MS QnA document.

Comment: Anyone from QnA maker service can explain this? It's very important in real practice.

Comment: Can you check your screenshots? Looks like some of them are missing, so we can't exactly see the changes. Maybe you could add the figures in the text?